# How to calculate relative percentage (apply score to a new range)?

Tags: javascript, math, pseudocode

I'm a front-end and back-end developer, and something that I've come across a few times when dealing with simple game development and animation is this challenge. I wish I had a function to solve for this, so I was hoping you math guys/gals could help me out with the pseudocode, and then I could post a function that we can run via the browser to test it.

It's a little hard for me to explain the challenge, so forgive me, I'm going to give it out like a riddle:

> You're trying to find your test score as a percent. You know that for a normal percent, expressed as a decimal from `0.00 - 1.00`, you'd do something like `actual_test_score / max_test_score`.
>
> However, you're not looking for any old percent. You'd like to express your percent as a decimal *within a specified range* of decimal numbers. For example, you'd like (given an `actual_test_score` and a `max_test_score`) to get your test score as a percent from `0.50 - 1.00`.
>
> How can you calculate `actual_test_score / max_test_score` expressed as a percentage between a range of `0.50 - 1.00`, instead of your typical range that is `0.00 - 1.00`.

It took kind of a while to explain this (and it might not be the best explanation) because it's not something I have to explain often, but again it's something I run into every now and then.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about math and not programming. Try [math.se] instead.

Comment: Much of programming is maths - so I personally consider this on topic. If the maths was more advanced then I would agree though.

Comment: @KenWhite this question is tagged math and I'm trying to express this logic as a function.

Comment: @shadow thank you. Rare members like you are exactly what keep this site alive and encouraging for new users with questions.

Comment: Heh thanks. Don't get me wrong though - I vote close many a question :P Just not ones that are so well expressed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a linear range mapping from [0,1] to [newMin,newMax], which is a specific case of the general linear range mapping from [oldMin,oldMax] to [newMin,newMax]:

```
function linearRemap(value, oldMin, oldMax, newMin, newMax) {
    var newScale = newMax - newMin;
    var valueAsPct = (val - oldMin) / (oldMax - oldMin);
    var scaledValue = valueAsPct * newScale;
    var shiftedAndScaledValue = scaledValue + newMin;
    return shiftedAndScaledValue;
}
```

So the limited case here permits you to skip the percent calculation line:

```
function linearRemapPct(valueAsPct, newMin, newMax) {
    var newScale = newMax - newMin;
    var scaledValue = valueAsPct * newScale;
    var shiftedAndScaledValue = scaledValue + newMin;
    return shiftedAndScaledValue;
}
```

Or just

```
function linearRemapPct(valueAsPct, newMin, newMax) {
    return (valueAsPct * (newMax - newMin) + newMin);
}
```

If you want to have something that's a bit more careful about loss of precision:

```
function linearRemapPct(valueAsPct, newMin, newMax) {
    return (valueAsPct * newMax) + (1 - valueAsPct) * newMin;
}
```

Comment: Even though in mathematics they use variables like a b and c, I think here on stack overflow we should encourage (and therefore demonstrate) self describing variable names. Yes they are longer - but they are significantly easier for people to read and understand, especially if you are either not the person who wrote the code or you are looking at your own code in a few years.

Comment: @shadow: Hmm. Usually in mathematical code variables are good so you can tie them into mathematical documentation. However, in this instance you're right as it's fairly simple and descriptive variable names would aid understanding, so I've relabelled them.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading this correctly, would you want `0` to be expressed as `0.5`?

In that case, you would need to multiply your number by the range of the score; `highest_score - lowest_score` which in your case appears to be `1 - 0.5`.
Then add the `lowest_score` to your result.

Here is an example in the form of a rough function;

```
function relative_percentage (score, max_score, min_score) {
    // score should be a value from 0 to 1.
    return score * (max_score - min_score) + min_score;
}
```

Comment: So `(.5, 20, 10)` would yield `10.25`?  That doesn't look right.  Your explanation looks correct, but the implementation doesn't.  Wouldn't it simply be `(score, max, min) => score * (max - min) + min` ?

Comment: The difference being that we divide by the difference in score rather than the max? Hmm, I think you're right. Updating now, I'll throw in some examples too.

Comment: I don't think that solution is correct... see https://jsfiddle.net/0hswa3ev/ In particular, a score of 30 with a max of 100 and min of 0 is giving me a result of 3000...

Comment: `score/max_score` is incorrect. `score` is a dimensionless value, `max_score` is in units of the new score range. You can only multiply `score` with something in a different unit.

Comment: Yep, that makes sense. If I make the `score` value take a percentage (ie, a value between `0` and `1`) then this makes more sense.